# Updating form in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

When I insert or update one form I have error:

> Spatial types and functions are not available for this provider because the assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types' version 10 or higher could not be found

But when I work on this project  on my ASP.NET MVC on Visual Studio every things work fine.
When I published my project my data showing without problems. Even I can insert or update some data on some table ond everything work fine. But after publish  when I want insert or update one form I have that error. When on my laptop I use IIS and  run this project everything ok. But on my IIS server I have that error. My SQL Server version is 2008 R2 and 2014 my problem still exist. I have `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` V16 but without this reference still work fine on some IIS.

I need to know why my project behavior like this.

Comment: _"my sql server version is 2008 r2"_ - why are you running an unsupported version? why can't you update to 2022?

Comment: *"When on my laptop I use IIS and run this project everything ok"* - hard to tell, are they having the exact some code and SQL Server version?

Comment: EF Core's support for SQL Server is SQL Server 2012 onwards, so 2008 R2 has been out of support since 2019. It should work with 2014 assuming you meant that you have tried it on a server with SQL Server 2014. Note that depending on EF Core version there can be breaking changes/bugs with older DB Providers. For instance EF Core 8 has a breaking bug with Contains  and SQL generation that doesn't work on SQL Server 2014 and older, including newer DBs with compatibility mode on.